# ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2. How to use it on Random Forest Regressor?

Tags: python, csv, flask, prediction

I have uploaded by csv file and try to predict from whole csv file. The model I have use is Random Forest Regressor to predict. I cannot able to predict whole csv file geeting this ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

```
@app.route("/multiple",methods=["GET","POST"])
@cross_origin()
def multiple():
if request.method == 'POST':
    file=request.form["csvfile"]
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        csv_reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")
        next(csv_reader,None) 
        data=[]
        for line in csv_reader:
            data.append(line)
            mul_prediction=model.predict([(np.array(data))])
            result=round(mul_prediction[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`RandomForestRegressor.predict` is expecting a 2-dimensional array.  When you put your data array in an enclosing list as in `model.predict([(np.array(data))])`, you are implicitly casting your 2-dimensional data to a 3-d array.  Instead, just use `model.predict(np.array(data))`.